# High Global Lock % on Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've just started using Mongodb v2.4.8 and the global lock % averages 80% which seems rather high to me. The CPU usage is around 120% on a 2 core, 2GB RAM, SSD VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. `iotop` shows occasional disk writes at around 10KB/s. `htop` shows that only 358 MB of memory is used out of 2GB.

2 Python processes continuously perform find/insert/update ops on mongo. The field used in the find operation is indexed.

Why is the global lock % so high? How can we troubleshoot this?

**MMS**

[image]

**db.serverStatus()**

```
    "myCollection" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(161149047),
            "w" : NumberLong(38511071963)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(11738433),
            "w" : NumberLong(6056873726)
        }
    },
```

**mongostat**

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults   locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
    *0     *0     73     *0       0    75|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:95.7%          0       0|0     0|0    13k    10k    13   15:56:06
    *0     *0     52     *0       0    54|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:83.6%          0       0|0     0|1     9k     8k    13   15:56:07
    *0     *0     67     *0       0    68|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:89.4%          0       0|0     0|0    12k     9k    13   15:56:08
     1      1     17      1       1   173|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:34.3%          0       0|0     0|1    18k    40k    13   15:56:09
    *0     *0     45     *0       0    46|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:69.2%          0       0|0     0|1     8k     7k    13   15:56:10
    *0     *0     46     *0       0    48|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0 testCollection:101.2%          0       0|0     0|1     8k     7k    13   15:56:11
    *0     *0     48     *0       0    50|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0 testCollection:100.5%          0       0|0     0|0     8k     8k    13   15:56:12
    *0     *0     62     *0       0    63|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:91.5%          0       0|0     0|0    11k     9k    13   15:56:13
    *0     *0     52     *0       0    53|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:94.4%          0       0|0     0|1     9k     8k    13   15:56:14
    *0     *0     34     *0       0    36|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:94.8%          0       0|0     0|1     6k     6k    13   15:56:15
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults   locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
     4      1      8      2       1   167|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:15.3%          0       0|0     0|1    17k    39k    13   15:56:16
    *0     *0     41     *0       0    43|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:97.4%          0       0|0     0|1     7k     7k    13   15:56:17
    *0     *0     45     *0       0    46|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:95.3%          0       0|0     0|1     8k     7k    13   15:56:18
    *0     *0     50     *0       0    52|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:90.0%          0       0|0     0|1     9k     8k    13   15:56:19
    *0     *0     57     *0       0    58|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:93.2%          0       0|0     0|1    10k     8k    13   15:56:20
    *0     *0     46     *0       0    48|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0 testCollection:105.6%          0       0|0     0|1     8k     7k    13   15:56:21
    *0     *0     58     *0       0    60|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:95.9%          0       0|0     0|0    10k     9k    12   15:56:22
     1      1     12      1       1   167|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:14.5%          0       0|0     0|1    16k    39k    13   15:56:23
    *0      1     49     *0       0    52|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:98.8%          0       0|0     0|1     9k    11k    13   15:56:24
    *0     *0     49     *0       0    51|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0 testCollection:101.9%          0       0|0     0|0     9k     8k    13   15:56:25
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults   locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
    *0     *0     49     *0       0    50|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:95.0%          0       0|0     0|1     8k     8k    13   15:56:26
    *0     *0     60     *0       0    62|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:94.2%          0       0|0     0|1    10k     9k    13   15:56:27
    *0     *0     46     *0       0    47|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:94.2%          0       0|0     0|1     8k     7k    13   15:56:28
    *0     *0     35     *0       0    38|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:90.6%          0       0|0     0|0     6k     6k    12   15:56:29
     1      1      1     *0       1   155|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0   testCollection:0.9%          0       0|0     0|0    15k    38k    13   15:56:30
     1     *0     42      1       0    45|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:93.3%          0       0|0     0|1     7k     7k    13   15:56:31
    *0     *0     57     *0       0    68|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:89.6%          0       0|0     0|1    10k    14k    13   15:56:32
    *0     *0     46     *0       0    48|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:91.9%          0       0|0     0|1     8k     7k    13   15:56:33
    *0     *0     53     *0       0    54|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:92.2%          0       0|0     0|1     9k     8k    13   15:56:34
    *0     *0     61     *0       0    63|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:89.3%          0       0|0     0|1    11k     9k    13   15:56:35
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults   locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
    *0     *0     40     *0       0    61|0       0  1.61g  3.42g   283m      0  testCollection:53.7%          0       0|0     0|0     9k     8k    13
```

**mongotop**

```
                    ns       total        read       write              2014-01-01T15:59:33
             testCollection.oooc       868ms         0ms       868ms
                 testCollection.         5ms         5ms         0ms
            testCollection.depth         0ms         0ms         0ms
   testCollection.system.indexes         0ms         0ms         0ms
testCollection.system.namespaces         0ms         0ms         0ms
     testCollection.system.users         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.oook         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.users         0ms         0ms         0ms

                    ns       total        read       write              2014-01-01T15:59:34
             testCollection.oooc       891ms         0ms       891ms
                 testCollection.         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.depth         0ms         0ms         0ms
   testCollection.system.indexes         0ms         0ms         0ms
testCollection.system.namespaces         0ms         0ms         0ms
     testCollection.system.users         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.oook         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.users         0ms         0ms         0ms

                    ns       total        read       write              2014-01-01T15:59:35
             testCollection.oooc       838ms         0ms       838ms
                 testCollection.         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.depth         0ms         0ms         0ms
   testCollection.system.indexes         0ms         0ms         0ms
testCollection.system.namespaces         0ms         0ms         0ms
     testCollection.system.users         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.oook         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.users         0ms         0ms         0ms

                    ns       total        read       write              2014-01-01T15:59:36
             testCollection.oooc       889ms         0ms       889ms
                 testCollection.         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.depth         0ms         0ms         0ms
   testCollection.system.indexes         0ms         0ms         0ms
testCollection.system.namespaces         0ms         0ms         0ms
     testCollection.system.users         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.oook         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.users         0ms         0ms         0ms

                    ns       total        read       write              2014-01-01T15:59:37
             testCollection.oooc       831ms         0ms       831ms
                 testCollection.         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.depth         0ms         0ms         0ms
   testCollection.system.indexes         0ms         0ms         0ms
testCollection.system.namespaces         0ms         0ms         0ms
     testCollection.system.users         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.oook         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.users         0ms         0ms         0ms

                    ns       total        read       write              2014-01-01T15:59:38
             testCollection.oooc       249ms         0ms       249ms
            testCollection.oook        62ms        62ms         0ms
                 testCollection.         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.depth         0ms         0ms         0ms
   testCollection.system.indexes         0ms         0ms         0ms
testCollection.system.namespaces         0ms         0ms         0ms
     testCollection.system.users         0ms         0ms         0ms
            testCollection.users         0ms         0ms         0ms
```

---

**Python Code**

This is the code that cause the slowdown pointed out by Adam C.

```
for date, row in oooc.T.iterkv():

    docExist = db.oooc.find({'timestamp': row['timestamp']})
    if docExist.count() == 0:
        data = json.loads(pd.concat([row, id]).to_json())
        db.oooc.insert(data)
    else:
        data = json.loads(row.to_json())
        db.oooc.update({'timestamp': data['timestamp']}, {'$set': data})
```

Comment: This is not directly a programming related question. There is no dealing with code anywhere here. As such, I would say that this question is better suited for [DBA Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database administration.

Comment: does the high lock % cause a problem, or is it mere "weirdness"?

Comment: @shx2 Before upgrading the server from 1 core to 2 cores, the CPU usage was always at 100%. With 2 cores its at 60%. I think it's better to deal with the high lock% now as I will need to increase the number of op/sec when I increase the number of python processes writing to mongo

Comment: I wouldn't worry about lock% unless you experience slowness

Comment: @Lix I have included the code that writes to mongodb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from `mongotop` is the clue you needed.  800+ milliseconds out of 1000ms, it runs once a second, is being spent writing in the `testCollection.oooc` namespace, so that is basically your culprit (800/1000 = ~80%).

Judging by your `mongostat` output it looks like those are updates, and for that relatively low level of updates to see that high a lock percentage I would assume you either have a lot of indexes on that collection or you are growing documents and causing them to move (or both).  Potentially they could be bulk updates so the true rate may be far higher than `mongostat` suggests.  Either way, figure out what you are doing to that collection, and then fix it.

**Update based on the provided code:**

It's hard to tell exactly what is happening without seeing what is in `data` in your code snippet, but note that any value for `docExist.count` that is greater than one could multiply the effect that I am about to describe.

When you initially write to a document in MongoDB, a specific amount of space is reserved for that document.  If you then add fields, expand an array, or grow the document in some other way beyond the original space allocation, then MongoDB must move the document to a new location (and allocate more space, which is does using the [padding factor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/#padding-factor)).

Hence, an operation that grows a document is very expensive versus an in-place update that can be done without a move.  Each such operation effectively becomes a delete and an insert.  There will also be a penalty related to index updates for each such move.

I suspect that your else clause with the update is triggering document growth and hence the locking you are seeing.  I would recommend altering this so that it is not triggering moves by either manually padding your initial inserts (so that updates can occur in place) or using one of the other [allocation strategies](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/#record-allocation-strategies).

Comment: Thank you for the analysis, the stats make more sense now! I've included in the original post the code that writes to `testCollection.oooc`. The `update` operation looks pretty simple to  me. The collection `oooc` only have an index on `timestamp`. What do you mean by growing documents and causing docs to move?

Comment: I amended the answer to explain things in more detail and relate it to the code posted

Comment: Just checked that collection's padding factor is `1.0`. Does this mean that during the update of a doc in that collection, even increasing the number of characters/digits in one of the fields will cause the docs to move? Like updating the value `99` to `100`

Comment: No, an increment such as the one listed is generally going to be in-place and not cause a move.  Moves will happen when a large portion of the document changes or is made larger (array additions, new fields etc.).  A padding factor of 1.0 would suggest no moves are happening btw, which would suggest your updates are causing that level of locking without moves (which seems strange).  I would look in the logs (or enable profiling for a while) to try to determine what are the slowest ops to narrow things down more